# Hide navigationbar in 1st view than use again swift ios 9

Tags: swift, ios9

i have two view Controller and i want to hied navigation bar in 1st view after that i want to use. i have already use self.navigation Controller? . navigation Bar Hidden = true

Comment: .... Really? How are we supposed to answer this? Share some code, share what you've tried and share whats going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In the view controller that you will hide the navitagionBar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true 
    }
```

and in

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false 
}
```